# Hide nodes when all connected edges are hided

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am trying to draw a graph with node and edges using cytoscape js.

edge info (there will be a lot of edges and nodes):

edge {
 id: ab
 source: a
 target: b
 attr1: 5,
 attr2: 3,
}

node info:

node {
  id: a
}

node: {
  id: b
}

I need to hide edges and nodes based on the range of attr1 and attr2. For example, hide edges with (attr1 > 5) and (attr2 > 7).

Also, when all edges connected to the node are hidded, I need to hide the node.

I tried to set visibility based on edge attribute 
http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/visibility

my nodes only have id attribute, I can only hide edges fulfil my select condition, but I cannot hide nodes when the connected edges are hidded.

```
{
        selector: 'edge',
        style: {
          'width': 3,

          display: function(ele) {

            if (ele.data('attr1') >= coeValue && ele.data('attr2') >= pValue){

              return 'element';
            } else {

              return 'none';
            }
          },

        },

      },

{
        selector: 'node',
        style: {
          shape: this.state.nodeShape,
          'background-color': function(ele) {
            if (ele.data('foldChange') > 25) {
              return "red";
            } else {
              return "green";
            }
          },
          label: 'data(id)',
          width: function(ele) {
            return ele.data('foldChange');
          },
          height: function(ele) {
            return ele.data('foldChange');
          },
          opacity: function(ele) {
            TODO:
                 if all connected edge hidden:
                    return 0;
                 else
                    return 1
          },
        }

      },
```

How can I hide nodes when all connected edges are hidden? Pls give some hints on the TODO part of the code